# Is there any way currently to browse an App Folder / App Sandbox on an iOS device with iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, filesystems

As a developer doing many operations with files in my own apps' sandboxes (An app's subfolder environment such as Documents folder etc.) on the device, I found it extremely useful to be able to browse my app folder to see if my code was writing things to the correct places etc. I always used to use iExplorer for this & it was vital. To my horror, I came to do the same browsing today, only to find that you can no longer look inside the app's folders with tools like iExplorer. Some research tells me that as of iOS 8.3, Apple have placed restrictions which stop these tools from doing the great job they did.

Is there a work-around now at the iOS9 stage or even any tools that still manage to do it? This was so essential as a dev.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean a physical device, not the Simulator. In that case, you could open the Devices window (Xcode > Window > Devices) and then select the relevant device on the left.

[image: Xcode Devices Window]

In the **Installed Apps** section, select your app, and then click the gear icon which will give you a menu to Show, Download or Replace Container...

Answer (score 0):

Now, it's available [FileBrowser](https://github.com/marmelroy/FileBrowser) to browse the content of an app folder (in its sandbox).